# sData REST APIs for sage 100 ERP

Tags: ruby, integration, sage-erp, sdata

I have a business partner account. And, I have setup sage SData and Sage ERP 100 on window server machine. I can access some resources in the browser like:

```
https://sage.lvh.me/SData/MasApp/MasContract/ABX/AR_Customer
```

It returns a huge file of XML.
My problem is that,
I need to integrate Sage ERP with my Rails application. Which will fetch products from Sage ERP and also make order for those products from rails application?

So, I need a complete sample API request which accepts some parameters (like page, perpage, type of request GET or POST) in request and return parseable XML/JSON response.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is some official api documentation like http://sage.github.io/SData-2.0/pages/core/0601/ ? Have you tried these examples?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with SData.  But I did find a link that will help: https://sagecity.na.sage.com/support_communities/sage100_erp/f/sage-100-business-object-interface/72926/sdata-install-training

From the read, it doesn't really look mature.

I use the SOTAMAS90 ODBC DSN to read Sage 100 data, and the Business Objects Interface (BOI) to write objects back to Sage 100.  For reading data, you just read like with any ODBC data source, providing the Connection string "DSN=SOTAMAS90; UID=; PWD=; Company = ABC"

For writing back to Sage you would typically use the BOI, which is a COM object that gets installed with Sage.  There is a ton of sample code on the BOI forum, which is here: https://sagecity.na.sage.com/support_communities/sage100_erp/f/sage-100-business-object-interface.

Good luck.  Let us know if you need more help.

Aaron